# Issue: selectizeInput() is parsing only first choice despite using multiple=TRUE in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using selectizeInput() to input choices as shown below:

```
selectizeInput(inputId="sample","Select ID",choices = NULL,multiple=TRUE)
```

The choices have been dynamically updated from a column in a file and it works fine. I would need to parse the selected choices as `comma` separated to the `input$sample` in the `system()` command within shiny as shown below:

```
system(paste0('-p \"IndividualID',input$sample,'\"'))
```

However, when more than one choice is made, only the first choice is parsed to `input$name`. How could we parse the choices as comma separated like 'choice1','choice2' to the `input$name` in the `system` command?

Comment: Maybe you want `paste(input$sample, collapse=",")`.

Comment: yes that works close as it parses them as `choice1,choice2`. I would need quotes for each choice like `'choice1', 'choice2'`

Comment: Try with `paste0("'",paste(input$sample, collapse="','"),"'")` then.

Comment: little clumsy but works though!! Thanks

Comment: sQuote(input$sample)